# Using Mockk to mock private function that takes a lambda

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I am trying to write a unit test for a implementation of an abstract class I wrote.  The method I'm trying to mock takes a lambda as it's only parameter.  I'm trying to capture this lambda, so I can invoke it and get the result.

This is the method I'm trying to mock:

```
protected fun update(block: suspend S.() -> S?): Unit
```

I am using an extension function in my tests like this:

```
suspend inline fun <reified T : Model<S>, S : State> T.blah(
    state: S,
    block: (T) -> Unit
): S? {
    val spy = spyk(this, recordPrivateCalls = true)
    val slot = slot<suspend S.() -> S?>()
    every { spy["update"](capture(slot)) } answers { Unit }

    block(spy)
    return slot.captured.invoke(state)
}
```

So I am creating a spy, then a slot, then when the update function is called, capture it so that it blocks the actual class from performing the call.  Then I invoke the lambda myself and return the value.

However I keep getting this error:

> io.mockk.MockKException: can't find function update(kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2$Subclass1@6bfa228c) for dynamic call
>
> at io.mockk.InternalPlatformDsl.dynamicCall(InternalPlatformDsl.kt:122)
>     at io.mockk.MockKMatcherScope$DynamicCall.invoke(API.kt:1969)

I followed the stacktrace and set a breakpoint in the `InternalPlatformDsl.kt` class, and traced it to this block of code:

```
for ((idx, param) in it.parameters.withIndex()) {
    val classifier = param.type.classifier
    val matches = when (classifier) {
        is KClass<*> -> classifier.isInstance(params[idx])
        is KTypeParameter -> classifier.upperBounds.anyIsInstance(params[idx])
        else -> false
    }

    if (!matches) {
       return@firstOrNull false
    }
}
```

It successfully matches the first parameter which is the class under test `Model` in this case, but it fails matching the second parameter because it is wrapped in the `capture` function.

Any ideas on how I can intercept this `update` call?

I'm using the latest version of mockk, and JUnit 4

Comment: What is `Model<S>` in your test?  Your test is referencing a **kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2**, which takes two arguments.